# Как передать значение свойства объекта в метод, инициализирующийся ссылкой на функцию

Tags: c++, typedef

Приведу упрощенный пример.
Имеем:

```
typedef void(*SomeFunc) (short id, char* data, int size)
//виртуальный канал
class Channel{
public:
    Channel(short c, SomeFunc w): id{ c }, write{ w } { };
private:
    short id; //номер канала
    SomeFunc write; //функция для обработки поступающих данных
}

//хранилище объектов канала
class Vault{
public:
    Vault(SomeFunc w): write{ w } { };
    void process(Packet packet)
    {
        ...
        //разбирает поступающий пакет, вычленяет номер канала и данные
        //если в векторе есть такой канал, то отдает данные его функции
        channels[i].write(id, data, size);
        //eсли нет - создает новый объект канала
        Channel channel{id, write};
        channel.write(id, data, size);
        channels.push_back(channel);
    }
private:
    vector<Channel> channels;
    SomeFunc write;
}
```

Определение класса Packet не так важно.
Используется всё примерно так:

```
void writeData(short id, char* data, int size)
{
    //например пишем номер канала, размер и данные в файл или выводим на экран
    std::cout<<"id: "<<id<<" size: "<<size<<"\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        std::cout<<data[i];
    }
}

Vault vault{&writeData};

CustomInputStream is{"some_file"} //Обертка над стандартным ifstream 
                                  //для чтения файла по пакетам
while(!is.eof){
    Packet packet=is.get();
    vault.process(packet);
}
```

В данной реализации приходится отдавать методу write объекта Channel номер канала в виде параметра. Существует ли при такой реализации способ получать внутри функции это значение из свойства объекта, от имени которого она вызывается(что-то вроде this)? Например:

```
void writeData(char* data, int size)
{

    std::cout<<"id: "<<this.id<<" size: "<<size<<"\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        std::cout<<data[i];
    }
}
```

Понятно, что сейчас так не сработает.

Comment: Добавьте в `SomeFunc` третий параметр `void *` или `uintptr_t` для передачи контекcта.

Comment: Судя по вашему коду, `writeData` это независимый сериализатор данных, он не зависит от канала. Чисто архитектурно это хороший интерфейс и не надо туда пихать `this.id`.